# How do I convert from a Dictionary to a SortedDictionary using LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

How to convert a Dictionary to a SortedDictionary?

In addition to general conversion (preserving types of key and values) I'm interested in swapping the keys and values as part of the conversion: have a `Dictionary<string, double>` and I want to convert it to a `SortedDictionary<double, string>`.

How do I do this using LINQ extension methods in C# 3.0?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Why use LINQ? There is a constructor for this:

```
new SortedDictionary<int, string>(existing);
```

You could *add* a `ToSortedDictionary` - but I wouldn't bother...

---

Note: this is an answer to the title of the question (convert a `Dictionary` to a `SortedDictionary`  for the same types, if you need additional step that OP is looking for - swap key and values in the process - as shown in the updated problem, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451717/how-do-i-convert-from-a-dictionary-to-a-sorteddictionary-using-linq-in-c#451900).

Comment: Just realized that I didn't back-quote the angle brackets in my original question.

Comment: I'm glad this is the accepted answer, despite it not answering what OP had intended to ask. It is definitely the right answer to the title question.

Answer (score 10):

No LINQ is needed.  SortedDictionary has a constructor to do the conversion.

```
public SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue> Convert<TKey,TValue>(Dictionary<TKey,TValue> map) {
  return new SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>(map);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer addresses conversion with swapping keys and values in the process.

It seems as though you are asking for an elegant way to take a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` and turn that into a `SortedDictionary<TValue,TKey>` (note that the value of the `Dictionary` is now the key of the `SortedDictionary`).

You could create an extension method that swaps keys and values of the dictionary into another dictionary:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static Dictionary<TValue, TKey> 
         AsInverted<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        var inverted = new Dictionary<TValue, TKey>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> key in source)
            inverted.Add(key.Value, key.Key);

        return inverted;
    }
}
```

And your application code would use that helper method to swap keys and values and use regular constructor of `SortedDictionary` like this:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<String, Double>();
        dict.Add("four", 4);
        dict.Add("three", 3);
        dict.Add("two", 2);
        dict.Add("five", 5);
        dict.Add("one", 1);

        var sortedDict = new SortedDictionary<Double, String>(dict.AsInverted());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need LINQ, just some nifty extension methods:

```
public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Sort<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    if(dictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
    }

    return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary);
}

public static IDictionary<TKey, TValue> Sort<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    if(dictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
    }

    if(comparer == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");
    }

    return new SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>(dictionary, comparer);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
    { 1, "one" },
    { 2, "two" },
    { 0, "zero" }
};

foreach(var pair in dictionary.Sort())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

// 0: zero
// 1: one
// 2: two
```

Answer (score 0):

Inversion using `ToDictionary`:

```
public static IDictionary<TValue, TKey> Invert<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary)
{
    if(dictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("dictionary");
    }

    return dictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Value, pair => pair.Key);
}
```

Example usage:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "zero", 0 },
    { "one", 1 },
    { "two", 2 }
};

foreach(var pair in dictionary.Invert())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

// 0: zero
// 1: one
// 2: two
```

Example of inverting and sorting (see my other answer for the definition of `Sort`):

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>
{
    { "one", 1 },
    { "two", 2 },
    { "zero", 0 }
};

foreach(var pair in dictionary.Invert().Sort())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

// 0: zero
// 1: one
// 2: two
```